# How to get an id that is different for each client (.i.e. a Mac address) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I Need a string that is different for each client, everything I can think of cant be obtained in JavaScript.

I have tried,

local ip's(because I have got the public ip server side),

MAC address

and Computer name.

Comment: In the browser or in node?

Comment: It's almost impossible. There's some technics called client fingerprinting that tries with some precision to archieve what you want, but isn't 100% precise.

Comment: What if you put a random cookie/token on each computer you access?

Comment: It is in the browser but I like @gatamborero idea  Thanks for the help